# Null en Inyección de dependencias

Tags: java, spring, javafx, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

Tengo un null pointer cuando hago el llamado al servicio. Estoy trabajando con IntellijIdea, Java 11, [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate). Por lo que estuve revisando las dependencias en el `pom.xml` no tienen nada que ver. Y el tema podría estar en `module-info.java`. Pero no estoy seguro. Anteriormente trabajé pero con spring-boot y no he tenido este inconveniente.

```
@Autowired private IPersonajeService personajeService;

@Component
public class HelloController {

@Autowired
private IPersonajeService personajeService;

@FXML
private Label welcomeText;

@FXML
protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
    Personaje guardar = new Personaje();
    guardar.setId(1L);
    guardar.setNombre("German");
    personajeService.nuevoPersonaje(guardar);
    welcomeText.setText("Listo!");
    }
}
```

El servicio:

```
package com.microsaga.game.service;

import com.microsaga.game.model.Personaje;

public interface IPersonajeService {
    void nuevoPersonaje(Personaje nuevoPersonaje);
}
```

La implementación:

```
package com.microsaga.game.service.impl;

@Service
public class PersonajeServiceImpl implements IPersonajeService {

    @Autowired
    private IPersonajeRepository personajeRepository;

    @Override
    public void nuevoPersonaje(Personaje nuevoPersonaje) {
        System.out.println("Se guardó nuevo personaje.");
    }
}
```

Estoy trabajando con JavaFx.

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste cambiar tu inyección a inyección por constructor como es la buena práctica?

Comment: Puedes mostrar todo el error que te esta arrojando porque puede ser cualquier cosa. La sugerencia es que en el controlador cambies por la palabra reservada @Controller Pero seria bueno que subas el error que te da.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema lo tienes en el primer código

```
@Autowired private IPersonajeService personajeService;
```

estas haciendo una inyección de dependencia fuera de la clase. Esta por encima.

```
@Component // cambiar también por @Controller
public class HelloController {
```

Comment: La declaración de atributos no puede ir fuera de la clase, eso no daría error de inyección, daría simplemente un error muy obvio que dice que se espera una clase, interfaz o enum en esa línea. En ningún momento llegaría a darle un nullPointerException